# How can I do a window that is always maximized?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli

I know that I can change the propertie 'WindowState' to 'Maximized' and also change the propertie 'MaximizeBox' to 'false', so my application starts maximized and there's no chance to restore my window by clicking on the restore button.

But I can drag the window and move down, so it automatically restores. Is there any way of universally blocking the restore?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about universal blocking but in addition to your settings like resetting MaximizeBox and windowState properties, You can block the restore of form using following code. Here, you have to subscribe for LocationChanged event of form

// inside construcotr

```
 this.LocationChanged += Form1_LocationChanged;
```

// global variable

```
 private Point desiredLocation;
```

and inside the event definition you will keep the form location persistent.

```
 void Form1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Location != desiredLocation)
            {
                this.Location = desiredLocation;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link https://vaibhavgaikwad.wordpress.com/2006/06/05/creating-a-immovable-windows-form-in-c/ and override the WndProc with the following code.

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{    
  const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
  const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;

  switch(message.Msg)
  {
      case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
         int command = message.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
         if (command == SC_MOVE)
            return;
         break;
  }

  base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms)

Comment: add related tags to the question.

Comment: Thank you for the notice

Answer (score 0):

For the Form Properties, On top of setting Form to start Maximized, and remove both the maximize box, and Minimize box, there is a setting called TopMost set this to True. The user can not minimize or move another application on top of your Application. 
[This photo Highlights property to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugXck.png)